# Beast combat in Scenario 19 (The Beastmaster)

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In Scenario 19, the Traitor's Tome says that certain beasts get extra successes when they initiate an attack. What does "extra successes" mean?

When we played, we assumed it meant add the number of successes to the roll, but we were not sure. For example, we added 2 to the total of the dice when the Bear initiated an attack.

Comment: Which edition of the game are you talking about? In mine (2nd ed. by WotC), there's no haunt called the Beastmaster... And the #19 is titled "A friend for the Ages".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the number of pips showing on any rolled die as a success.

Then, a standard creature/character rolling one die has a range of possibilities from 0-2.  Let's say a creature got to roll one die, but had one additional succcess.  Then that creature rolls a die (normal 0-2 distribution) and adds one.  So, their overall distribution is 1-3.

The impact of this is that the creature will **always** have some successes that must be defended against.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the revised rules for adding "success," but it looks like it might just be a typo. When the game wants you to roll another die, it will use the word die/dice.

> The Book contains chess strategies. The explorer who has it can add
>   one die (maximum eight dice) to Knowledge rolls attempted while
>   playing chess against Death.

I can't find the term "extra success" in the revised rulebook, so [here's](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_TraitorRev_120105.pdf) the errata.

> The Bear adds 2 successes to its Might attack roll when it initiates
>   an attack (not when it's being attacked). The Crocodile adds 1 success
>   to its Might attack roll when it initiates an attack (not when it's
>   being attacked).

And always remember the golden rule.

> What If There Isn’t a Rule for That? Many hours went into playtesting
>   this game, but it’s still possible you’ll run into situations where
>   the game rules or haunt books don’t clearly answer a question about
>   game play. Don’t let that slow you down. In such cases, come to an
>   agreement as a group for what makes the most sense and go with it. (If
>   that doesn’t work, fl ip a coin to decide.) Then continue your
>   experience in the house.